# Javascript - Can I make this table scroll to top?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have to make a self-scrolling table. I tried using this:
https://codepen.io/salman31/pen/dYdGLa

```
    var my_time;
$(document).ready(function() {
  pageScroll();
  $("#contain").mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout(my_time);
  }).mouseout(function() {
    pageScroll();
  });
});

function pageScroll() {  
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("contain");
  objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollTop + 1;  
  $('p:nth-of-type(1)').html('scrollTop : '+ objDiv.scrollTop);
  $('p:nth-of-type(2)').html('scrollHeight : ' + objDiv.scrollHeight);
  //if (objDiv.scrollTop == (objDiv.scrollHeight - 50)) {
    objDiv.scrollTop = 0;
  //}
  my_time = setTimeout('pageScroll()', 25);
}
```

And it works, but it doesn't automatically scroll back to top when it hits the "bottom". What do I need to change?

Thank you!

Comment: why did you comment out the if statement? Is the html and css identical to the codepen example?

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
var my_time;
$(document).ready(function() {
  pageScroll();
  $("#contain").mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout(my_time);
  }).mouseout(function() {
    pageScroll();
  });

  $('#contain').bind('scroll', function()
     {
       if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()>=$(this)[0].scrollHeight)
          {
              pageScroll();
          }
     })
});

function pageScroll() {  
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("contain");
  objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollTop + 1;  
  $('p:nth-of-type(1)').html('scrollTop : '+ objDiv.scrollTop);
  $('p:nth-of-type(2)').html('scrollHeight : ' + objDiv.scrollHeight);
  if (objDiv.scrollTop == (objDiv.scrollHeight - 100)) {
    objDiv.scrollTop = 0;
  }
  my_time = setTimeout('pageScroll()', 25);
}
```

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't work. it just stops at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
objDiv.scrollTop = 0
```

is what's supposed to reset the scroll position, using the if statement you've got commented to execute it only once it's finished scrolling up. With the if statement commented out, the table shouldn't be scrolling at all, as the pageScroll function will always set the scrollTop property to 0.

Try uncommenting the if statement, and making sure that you're subtracting the height of your container from objDiv.scrollHeight in the comparison.

Comment: sorry. this is what I had before. but even when it's not commented out, it just stops at the bottom

Comment: What's being output into the scrollTop and scrollHeight paragraph tags on your page?